# sed with simultaneous and sequential replace

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

I'm not sure this is possible to do what I want in sed (or awk or any bash tool):

I want to make a script that replaces `: )` in a string by `<happy>` and `) :` by `<sad>`. This can easily be done with sed with:

```
echo "test : )" | sed 's/: )/<happy>/g'
echo "test ) :" | sed 's/) :/<sad>/g'
```

Unfortunately, sometimes I have strings like these:

```
I'm happy : ) : ) : )
I'm sad ) : ) : ) :
```

In that case, the output should be:

```
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
```

But by combining the two commands above:

```
echo "I'm happy : ) : ) : )" | sed 's/: )/<happy>/g' | sed 's/) :/<sad>/g'
echo "I'm sad ) : ) : ) :" | sed 's/: )/<happy>/g' | sed 's/) :/<sad>/g'
```

I will get:

```
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad ) <happy> <happy> :
```

The way to solve this would be to do both replacements in parallel, by treating the string from left to right. I tried to use something like this: `sed 's/a/b/g;s/c/d/g'` but the replacement is only done one pattern after one other, and doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat script1.awk
BEGIN {
    map[": )"] = "<happy>"
    map[") :"] = "<sad>"
}
{
    while ( match($0,/(.*)(: \)|\) :)(.*)/,a) ) {
        $0 = a[1] map[a[2]] a[3]
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f script1.awk file
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
```

With any awk:

```
$ cat script2.awk
BEGIN {
    map[": )"] = "<happy>"
    map[") :"] = "<sad>"
}
{
    while ( match($0,/: \)|\) :/) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) map[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f script2.awk file
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
```

Although both approaches produce the same output in this case, the first approach actually works from the end of the string to the front courtesy of the leading `.*` while the second approach works front to back. You can see that with this test:

```
$ echo ': ) :' | awk -f script1.awk
: <sad>

$ echo ': ) :' | awk -f script2.awk
<happy> :
```

You can do a back-to-front pass with any awk with a tweak but I don't think that's what you really want anyway.

---

Edit to build the regexp from the map:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    map[": )"] = "<happy>"
    map[") :"] = "<sad>"
    for (emoji in map) {
        gsub(/[^^]/,"[&]",emoji)
        gsub(/\^/,"\\^",emoji)
        emojis = (emojis == "" ? "" : emojis "|") emoji
    }
}
{
    while ( match($0,emojis) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) map[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks! It is actually great because one can even put more emojis in the `map`. Is there a simple way to concatenate the keys of `map` and put that in the `match` function automatically?

Comment: Sure, I just added a version that does that.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Perl available, it does a good job of this problem. Its `e` option on substitutions makes the code short and - for Perl - tidy.

```
my %map = (
    ": )" => "<happy>",
    ") :" => "<sad>",
);

while (<>) {
    s/\: \)|\) \:/$map{$&}/ge;
    print;
}
```

The general case - where the regular expression is built from the map - is solved in the script below. The subtlety in Perl is that its regular expression engine matches the first matching pattern in an `|` alternation. The upshot is that the alternatives need to be sorted longest to shortest, otherwise, in the example below, `: ))` might get matched by `: )`.

```
$ cat script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my %map = (
    ": )" => "<happy>",
    ") :" => "<sad>",
    ": |" => "<meh>",
    ": ))" => "<really happy>",
);

my @map_regexes = keys %map;
my @map_regexes_longest_first = reverse sort @map_regexes;
my @quoted_map_regexes = map(quotemeta, @map_regexes_longest_first);
my $map_regex = join("|", @quoted_map_regexes);

while (<>) {
    s/$map_regex/$map{$&}/ge;
    print;
}
$ cat file.txt
I'm happy : ) : ) : )
I'm sad ) : ) : ) :
I'm meh : | : | : |
I'm really happy : )) : )) : ))
$ perl -w script.pl <file.txt
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
I'm meh <meh> <meh> <meh>
I'm really happy <really happy> <really happy> <really happy>
```

Answer (score 2):

For given sample (i.e dealing with two overlapping matches), one can use looping and solve with `sed` as well

```
$ cat ip.txt
I am happy : ) : ) : )
I am sad ) : ) : ) :
: ) : ) : )
) : ) : ) :
) : : ) :
: ) ) :

$ # GNU version: sed -E -e ':a s/(^|[^)].): \)/\1<happy>/g; ta' -e 's/\) :/<sad>/g'
$ sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/(^|[^)].): \)/\1<happy>/g' -e 'ta' -e 's/\) :/<sad>/g' ip.txt
I am happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I am sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
<happy> <happy> <happy>
<sad> <sad> <sad>
<sad> <happy> :
<happy> <sad>
```

- `-e ':a'` label `a`
- `s/(^|[^)].): \)/\1<happy>/g` replace `: )` with `<happy>` as long as 2nd character before it is not `)`
- `-e 'ta'` branch to label `a` if there was successful substitution - looping is required because we have to check 4 characters for one replacement of 2 characters
- `s/\) :/<sad>/g` once all the happy emojis are replaced, we can change all the sad emojis in one go

For multiple mappings, here's a `perl` solution similar to the `awk` one

```
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $h{": )"}="<happy>"; $h{") :"}="<sad>";
                   $r = join "|", map quotemeta, keys %h; }
            s/$r/$h{$&}/g' ip.txt
I am happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I am sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
<happy> <happy> <happy>
<sad> <sad> <sad>
<sad> <happy> :
<happy> <sad>
```

- `$h{": )"}="<happy>"` create hash of key-value pairs
- `$r = join "|", map quotemeta, keys %h` create regex alternation from all the keys of hash `%h`... `map quotemeta` will escape all characters other than `[A-Za-z_0-9]` for each hash key
- `s/$r/$h{$&}/g` search and replace

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem in two passes:

1. Identify the replaceable strings, and mark them with delimiters (I'll use `!` for both start and end, but you can use almost anything).
2. Now replace those delimited strings separately.

Here's a sed program that implements this approach:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -f

s/) :\|: )/!&!/g


s/!: )!/<happy>/g
s/!) :!/<sad>/g
```

---

A note on the the delimiters:

We can use any delimiter we want for this, as we always re-match and replace the delimiters we introduce.  This isn't the case in all sed scripts, and as a general rule it can be a good idea to use `\n` as delimiter (if you're processing single lines) or another unlikely character (perhaps `\0` or `\377` if you're processing ordinary text).

We can use any character in this script.  For example, using `a` and `b` works just as well:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -f

s/) :\|: )/a&b/g

s/a: )b/<happy>/g
s/a) :b/<sad>/g
```

```sh
$ sed -f ../stackoverflow/51886023.sed <<<$'I\'m happy : ) : ) : )\nI\'m sad ) : ) : ) :'
```

```
I'm happy <happy> <happy> <happy>
I'm sad <sad> <sad> <sad>
```

Comment: Consider using `\n` as the delimiters since `\n` can't exist in a sed input line (assuming you're not using wacky, arcane sed constructs to build up multiple lines in a buffer).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the delimiter is already present in the line anywhere - you can't get an accidental match that way.  We only match and replace those we added.  (But yes, good advice in general to use `\n` as an "impossible" character when you're processing single lines - mind you, I wouldn't call `N` and friends "wacky" or "arcane", given that literally [the first of the "Examples"](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Joining-lines.html) in the manual uses them!)

Comment: Those examples are all things that you should never do with sed since the awk equivalent is always clearer, simpler, easier to enhance/maintain and usually more efficient and more portable. They're like examples of how to hammer nails with a screwdriver when you have both a hammer and a screwdriver in your toolbag - sure you CAN do it, but it's not something a carpenter would recommend. e.g. to join backslash-continued lines they show `sed -e ':x /\\$/ { N; s/\\\n//g ; bx }'  1.txt` - hilarious (and non-portable)!

Comment: Yeah, that's true.